# Issue setting up environment variable for Java

Tags: java, windows-10

Having an issue setting up system environment variable for Java in Windows 10 (see image):

[image: Screenshot-system Variable]

From command prompt is does not recognise `javac -version`. As you can see from the image I have setup `JAVA_HOME` and set the path to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. Any suggestion

Comment: Can you try to reboot? Configuration seems to be ok.
Before reboot, you can also try to close and open a new cmd shell, if you didn't try yet

Comment: did you start a new command prompt (`cmd.exe`) after applying system properties?

Comment: you might as well have another `JAVA_HOME` or `PATH` entry in **User variables** overriding these.

Comment: command prompt was only opened after the system variables had been set and yes I have rebooted the system also and have tried adding it to User variables as well

Comment: what happens if you get rid of the user variables for `JAVA_HOME` and bin entry in `PATH` and just use the system variables?

Comment: If you enter the command `set Path`, what is the output?

Comment: Have managed to resolve this now by deleting both entries, rebooting the laptop, re-entering the same details, rebooting the laptop but had same issue, rebooted the laptop once more and now it works. What a ball ache, but thanks for the help.